# Why does the fragment reset the activity it goes to?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have a navigational bar (a bunch of buttons) in a fragment and I'm trying to have it on every page of my app.

When I interact with the homepage and change the text to abc on a button and then click the navigational bar fragment, I am successfully taken to the next page. When I hit android's given back button, the app successfully moves back to the activity with the text changed to abc.

However, if I change the text to abc then click the nav bar to a new page and then click the nav bar back to the home page, the text has been reset to the original values and not abc.

I'm not really sure how else to explain the problem, anyone have any clues or want more clarification?

Comment: Please share the your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is challenging to understand your app functionality without code base and UI. From my understanding, I believe you are not using the **savedInstancestate** bundle object to save your data whenever you are clicking the back button on the nav bar. You must bundle your data before going back to your activity or launching a new activity/fragment if you want to save your text changes. Look into two things:

1. Activity/Fragment lifecycle.
2. SavedInstanceState

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment need tag or id when adding/replace in order to restore.

```
    String mCurrentOverlayFragmentTag = "ControlOverlayFragment";
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.overlayHolder, fragment, mCurrentOverlayFragmentTag)
            .commit();
```